# Cluster point for a net

Tags: general-topology, nets

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha \in A}$ be a net in $X$. For $\alpha$, define $E_{\alpha}=\left\{x_{\beta}:\alpha\lesssim \beta\right\}$.

Is it true that :

$x$ is a cluster point of $\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha \in A}$ if and only if  $x\in \cap_{\alpha\in A} \overline{E_{\alpha}}$.

Here $x$ is a Cluster point for the  net $\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha \in A}$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ ,  $<x_{\alpha}>$ is frequently in $U$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please state the definition  of "cluster point" in the question above. You will then see, probably with a change of notation, whether or not the above statement is true.

Comment: I edited the question now

Comment: If $x$ is a cluster point, then fix $\alpha \in A$. We want to show that $x \in \overline{E_\alpha}$. So fix any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, and ... use the definition of cluster point, it is clear from here. Also, expand out what "is frequently in" means mathematically, then the answer is almost clear.(This is one way, and the other should be similar).

Comment: Can you please give  more details so I can follow you easily ? Thanks

Comment: I will do so, by writing an answer.

Comment: Thank you Actoh, I really appreciate it

Comment: By the way, I had a small  question : you have a net, so it is coming from some directed set. My question is, is the order given by $\leq$ or $\geq$? Because, from how you have defined $E_{\alpha}$ above, I think it is all elements appearing *before* $\alpha$ in the order, whereas for the statement to hold, $E_{\alpha}$ has to consist of all elements appearing *after* $\alpha$ in the order.

Comment: @ I am sorry I just discovered a typo, I will edit the question, I am so sorry

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, i just edited the question, sorry about that.

Comment: Perfect. So much better. By the way, I shall give $+1$ for your question as well. I shall proceed to write the answer.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, thank you very much for all your help and consideration.

Comment: The answer is up! Do give feedback, it makes me happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we want to show that $x$ is a cluster point if and only if $x \in \cap_\alpha \overline E_\alpha$.

Definition : $x$ is a cluster point of $x_\alpha$ if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, $x_\alpha$ is frequently in $U$.

Translating this mathematically gives : $x$ is a cluster point of $x_\alpha$ if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and $\alpha_0 \in A$, there is some $\beta \geq \alpha_0$ such that $x_\beta$ is in $U$.

---

Let us start with $x$ as a cluster point. We want to show that it is in the intersection of $\overline E_\alpha$, so fix some $\alpha_0$. We want to show that $x \in \overline E_{\alpha_0}$, so we will pick any neighburhood of $x$, call it $U$. By definition of cluster point, there is some $\beta \geq \alpha_0$ such that $x_{\beta} \in U$. But then, $x_{\beta} \in E_{\alpha_0}$.

So what have we shown? We have shown that every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ has non-empty intersection with $E_{\alpha_0}$. Thus, $x$ is in the closure of $E_{\alpha_0}$, and now $\alpha_0$ was fixed but arbitrary, so this statement is true for all $\alpha \in A$, showing one direction.

---

The other way, suppose that $x \in \cap_\alpha \overline E_{\alpha}$. We want to show that $x$ is a cluster point. So fix any neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, and any $\alpha_0 \in A$. We know that $x \in \overline E_{\alpha_0}$, so that any neighbourhood of $x$, in particular $U$, has non-empty intersection with $E_{\alpha_0}$. So there is some $x_{\beta} \in E_{\alpha_0}$ which belongs to $U \cap E_{\alpha}$, but then $\beta \geq \alpha_0$ by definition of $E_{\alpha_0}$.

What have we shown? We have shown that for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and $\alpha_0 \in A$, there is $\beta \geq \alpha$ such that $x_{\beta} \in U$. This is the definition of cluster point.

Hence, we complete the proof.

Comment: @ астон вілла олоф, thank you very much for all your help, such a good  and detailed solution, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you like, you may upvote and accept, since this answer satisfies all your requirements.